# select statement to truncate and append column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, inner-query

i have a table which contains columns

```
[id],[StartsWith],[Length] ,[MinExt] ,[MaxExt],[isDID] ,[DeleteDigits] ,[AppendDigits]

208 ,     61     ,    5    ,  61000  ,  61999 ,   0    ,       2       ,   22058

209 ,     63     ,    5    ,  63000  ,  63999 ,   0    ,       2       ,  26518
```

now let suppose if user sends a number say 61205 i have to check that in which row that number(i.e 61205) exist by checking between MinExt and MaxExt

after that i have to truncate x digits from 61205 mentioned in corresponding deleteDigits from the start of the number (in this case 2 digits will be truncated) after truncate i have to append 205 in last of [appenddigits] column. 
    which will make a complete number like 22058205.

i have to do this through select statement as it will be an inner query. or if anyone can suggest something else i will be very thankful.

Comment: Are you sure the expected result is 22058205?  truncate usually means remove last digits and append usually occurs at the end so a number of 61222058 seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: every time will you take last 3 digits or you truncate first 2 digits?

Comment: I'll give you a trace: use SUBSTRING, use CAST, use WHERE and use + operator...

Comment: What data type is expected for output?

Comment: @xQbert yes final result should be 22058205

Comment: @Rams length of the number could be any number in this case its 5 but length can vary. or truncated digits will be the number in deletedigit column.

Comment: @abhi its not a homework or any assignment. i am doing a project for a company.

Comment: @xQbert output datatype will be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(100) = '61205'

SELECT AppendDigits + SUBSTRING(@VAL, 3, LEN(@VAL) - 2)
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  CAST(@VAL AS int) BETWEEN MinExt AND MaxExt
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need solution as a inner query

Comment: I am marking this as answer as i changed my requirement from inner query to stored procedure and then i used your query. thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup table mentioned in your question has few rows, you could use a multi-level Case Statement to do this. Although it would look cumbersome, it will do the job perfectly without dependence on other code.

If this table is likely to have many rows, you may want to use a SQL Server User-Defined function.

Comment: lookup table has many rows more than 4000. and for userdefined function means i have to call function for every number(if user is sending more than one number)?

Comment: Thanks for your advice i created a stored procedure and then implemented the lopic. thanks again

Comment: Ok. Just saying for future needs of similar nature, the use of a user-defined function (in-line functions) will help you to still use it in select query or an inner query. Have a good day.